# Can Qfield be used with external GNSS service?

Tags: gps, android, qfield

I'm currently testing an external GNSS service on my mobile device. It produces RTK corrected GNSS signal that is distributed over bluetooth as NMEA format.

Is Qfield able to read an external GNSS service? App's settings don't seem to include anything concerning this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connecting external devices with NMEA support via bluetooth is possible since [version 1.8.0](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v1.8.0).

External GNSS services can be used via tools like rtklib which can then convert the position to a mock location.

<strike>Directly working on the NMEA data is not (yet) possible.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can use Apps to mock positions, so you have the external GPS as internally for all Apps.
Unlock developer settings and select your (previously installed) App for mock GPS positions there.
rtklib is useful, if you want to handle NTRIP on the device, if you get corrected postitions via NMEA already (GSM + NTRIP handled by GPS receiver).

If you have a bluetooth connection to your GPS device, you may look at 'Bluetooth GPS' (tested successfully), there are similar ones for serial connection over cable (via OTG and usb2serial, this is not very practical in the field).
Untested:
https://www.f-droid.org/en/packages/org.broeuschmeul.android.gps.usb.provider/